# high speed interprocess associative array

Tags: c++, dictionary, ipc, interprocess, associative

Is there library usable from c++ for sharing fairly simple data (integers,floating point numbers, strings) between cooperative processes?

Must be :

- high-speed (SQL-based methods too slow due to parsing)
- able to get,set,update,delete both fixed and variable data types (e.g. int and string)
- ACID (atomic,consistent,isolated,durable)
- usable under linux
- usable by processes without a shared parent.
- highly compatible license: e.g. LGPL,MIT,BSD

For bonus points:

- ability to work across the network.
- ability to handle aggregation/composition into more complicated structures

Comment: I didnt used it, but did you investigate the capabilities of D-Bus for IPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [boost::interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/interprocess.html).  For local use, you probably can't beat a map or hash table in shared memory.  Allowing networking makes things more difficult, in that case something like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) or [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) might be more appropriate.

Comment: There is a discussion of using STL and Boost containers with Boost.InterProcess: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.containers_explained

Comment: I was just looking for that, thanks.  Being able to use the same classes for shared-memory data structures as in "normal" code is pretty darn slick.